# Authenticated Network share as ActiveMQ producer

Tags: activemq-classic, messaging

I am trying to set up a pretty basic messaging system with ActiveMQ.

I have a network share that another program puts XML files into.

I have an ActiveMQ route set up that I think should be delivering files that are dropped into the network share to my ActiveMQ queue.  I am not getting the files delivered to my queue and believe it is because I need to authenticate to the network share.

Can someone help me figure out where in my config files I need to put my NETWORK username and password so the share is accessible to the ActiveMQ?

Or am I going about this completely wrong?  I am using the out of the box config for activeMQ and Camel with the exception of my route:

```
<route>

            <description>Leslie Odyssey Route</description>

            <from uri="file://servername.domain.gov/MetroFileDrop"/>

            <to uri="activemq:queue:Odyssey.Queue"/>
</route>
```

In my ActiveMQ command prompt console I see the following:

```
INFO| Route: route2 started and consuming from:
Endpoint[file://servername.domain.gov/MetroFileDrop]
```

which makes me believe that the route IS there but I never get any files delivered.

Thanks for any info,
Leslie

Comment: So I just noticed that when I start my ActiveMQ it creates this folder on the local C drive...what I need is for it to monitor and connect to an existing network folder location....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a folder on your local harddrive that points to your network store and point your camel route to that folder. camel alone doesnt understand network folders.

Comment: Ok, I will give that a try...what I did in the mean time was mapped a drive to that folder (putting my credentials in the mapping) and I used the correct UNC in the route (////servername.domain.gov//MetroFileDrop) and that seems to have worked, but you are saying that I don't need to map the drive?  How can I pass credentials by creating a folder that points to the share?

Comment: no, what i meant was exactly what you did as a workarount. map your network drive to a local folder and point camel to that folder.